# fgetc requires 'enter' key pressed twice on WINDOWS

Tags: c, windows, passwords, fgetc

I'm trying to make a password input mask function that's portable between windows, linux, and osx. So far I have code that works perfectly in linux and osx, but windows is giving me one issue.

Does anyone know why in windows fgetc requires me to press the `enter` key twice before it exits the while loop?

```
static int get_password(char *password, int mask)
{
    int max_pass_len = 512;

#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode = 0;
    DWORD prev_mode = 0;
    GetConsoleMode(hstdin, &mode);
    GetConsoleMode(hstdin, &prev_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(hstdin, mode & ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT));
#else
    static struct termios prev_terminal;
    static struct termios terminal;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &prev_terminal);

    memcpy (&terminal, &prev_terminal, sizeof(struct termios));
    terminal.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    terminal.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    terminal.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &terminal);
#endif

    size_t idx = 0;         /* index, number of chars in read   */
    int c = 0;

    const char BACKSPACE = 8;
    const char RETURN = 13;

    /* read chars from fp, mask if valid char specified */
    while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != RETURN && c != EOF && idx < max_pass_len - 1) ||
            (idx == max_pass_len - 1 && c == 127))
    {
        if (c != 127 && c != BACKSPACE) {
            if (31 < mask && mask < 127)    /* valid ascii char */
                fputc(mask, stdout);
            password[idx++] = c;
        } else if (idx > 0) {         /* handle backspace (del)   */
            if (31 < mask && mask < 127) {
                fputc(0x8, stdout);
                fputc(' ', stdout);
                fputc(0x8, stdout);
            }
            password[--idx] = 0;
        }
    }
    password[idx] = 0; /* null-terminate   */

// go back to the previous settings
#ifdef _WIN32
    SetConsoleMode(hstdin, prev_mode);
#else
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &prev_terminal);
#endif

    return idx; /* number of chars in passwd    */
}
```

```

Comment: `((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != RETURN && c != EOF && idx < max_pass_len - 1) ||
            (idx == max_pass_len - 1 && c == 127)` is faily complex.  Consider re-coding to make clear its intent.

Comment: Windows is an OS, yet the issue is certainly compiler related.  What _compiler_ are you using?

Comment: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc I'm cross compiling on linux for windows 64bit

Comment: The x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc may be converting the enter key into `"\r\n"`.  If so, on all platforms,  test for input `\r` and `continue`.  Something like `while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF) { if (c=='\r') continue; if (idx == ...) break; ... } `.

Comment: What happens the first time you press Enter? Is the loop entered? If so, what is `c`?

Comment: The loop is not entered on the first enter press. On the second press the loop is exited and the value of c was 13

Comment: As reported in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376492/fgetc-requires-enter-key-pressed-twice-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment75755651_44376492), exactly what keys were pressed?  What was the value of `c` on the first enter press?  Does code do any prior I/O?

Comment: Function starts.
c = 0.
I press `Enter` key.
c = 13.
Nothing happens.
I press `Enter` key again.
c is set to 13 again, but this time it exits the while loop.

Comment: Solved using `ReadConsole`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved using ReadConsole

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    long unsigned int char_read = 0;
    while ((ReadConsole(hstdin, &c, 1, &char_read, NULL) && c != '\n' && c != RETURN && c != EOF && idx < max_pass_len - 1) ||
            (idx == max_pass_len - 1 && c == BACKSPACE))
#else
    while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF && idx < max_pass_len - 1) ||
            (idx == max_pass_len - 1 && c == 127))
#endif
```